# How to make webpack to inject script links into HTML server file?

Tags: reactjs, flask, webpack, bundling-and-minification

My application is Flask-based and I'm using webpack to build JS (React is used for frontend).

When I was trying to use dynamic import I faced the problem it can't find 0.bundle.js file. It's pretty obvious, why: because I didn't include it. My html file is loaded from the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ url_for("static", filename="favicon.ico") }}" />
    </head>
    <body class="main">
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="{{ url_for("static", filename="dist/main.bundle.js")}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the webpack config fragment:

```
entry: {
    main: './src/app/dashboard/main.jsx'
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/dist')
},
```

Of course, if I add the following line everything is working:

```
<script src="{{ url_for("static", filename="dist/0.bundle.js")}}"></script>
```

But it's not good because I don't want to guess what will be the next chink if any.

How to configure it properly?

This example https://github.com/thatisuday/js-plugin-starter looks pretty much the same but I can't figure out how they handle this problem.

I also found that this plugin can help 'html-webpack-plugin' but not sure how to configure it (at least I didn't succeed yet).

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the publicPath into webpack config:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/dist'),
    publicPath: 'static/dist/',
    chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
},
```